# How to enumerate all controls hold by a TCategoryPanel?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a TCategoryPanelGroup which contains a single TCategoryPanel (named CatPan). CatPan contains 3 listboxes.

I want to automatically resize the CatPan to match the height of the 3 listboxes it contains. But CatPan does not have an AutoSize property. Therefore, I need to enumerate the listboxes to get their height.

However, I get nothing when I try to enumerate the 3 listboxes:

```
for i= 0 to CatPan->ControlCount-1 do CatPan[i].Height;
```

because CatPan.ControlCount returns 1 instead of 3!!! It seems that the CapPan is not the parent of the listboxes. Probably it is doing so in order to be able to do the collapse/expand animation.

I called lbox1->Parent->Name (lbox1 is one of the listboxes) to see who is its parent but it returns an empty string.

Comment: You almost answer your own question. The list boxes are in the TCategoryPanel, not the TCategoryPanelGroup. Just use that instead. You don't give enough information to be more precise.

Comment: Yes. The list boxes are placed into the CatPan. How, do I enumerate them?

Comment: @Dsm - I think you miss-read the question :) :). .... Or maybe I am not very clear? Let me know....

Comment: Calling lbox1->Parent->Name (lbox1 is one of the listboxes) also returns an empty string. It shouldn't since all the controls on my form have name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing that TCategoryPanel creates TCategoryPanelSurface Object as its child in it's constructor, therefore all controls go into TCategoryPanelSurface Object and NOT into TCategoryPanel.

In C++ Builder it goes like:

```
ShowMessage(ListBox1->Parent->ClassName()); //you can see actual parent class here
TCategoryPanelSurface  * Surface;
Surface = dynamic_cast <TCategoryPanelSurface *> (CatPan->Controls[0]);
ShowMessage(Surface->ControlCount);
ShowMessage(Surface->Controls[0]->Name); //you should use loop here to iterate through controls
```

In Delphi:

```
var
  Surface: TCategoryPanelSurface;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Surface := CatPan.Controls[0] as TCategoryPanelSurface;
  for I := 0 to Surface.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(Surface.Controls[I].Name);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You should be using `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I am new to C++. Can you shortly explain why. When converting between VCL objects, all code I have seen used dynamic_cast

Comment: @Rigel `static_cast` is evaluated at compile time and has no runtime overhead. In Delphi, this is the same as `Surface := TCategoryPanelSurface(CatPan.Controls[0]);`. Use this when you KNOW the object type ahead of time. `dynamic_cast` is evaluated at runtime and relies on RTTI. In Delphi, this is equivalent to `if CatPan.Controls[0] is TCategoryPanelSurface then Surface := TCategoryPanelSurface(CatPan.Controls[0]) else Surface = nil;`. Use this when you need to DISCOVER the object type dynamically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Well, knowing Embarcadero/Idera implications to "add new stuff" i'd rather stick with dynamic_cast. My insight is if they decide to change TCategoryPanelSurface to "BetterTCategoryPanelSurface" They'd probably make it derived from TCategoryPanelSurface, which would allow my code to work anyway. Beside a little overhead what is the downside ?

Comment: As long as `BetterTCategoryPanelSurface` derives from `TCategoryPanelSurface`, the static cast would continue to work just fine.  On the other hand, this code is relying on an *implementation detail* that could change in the future. A better solution would be to [file a feature request](https://quality.embarcadero.com) to Embarcadero asking for a better and stable API to access the child controls.